# SQL error: Operand sollte 1 Spalte(n) enthalten/should contain one coloumn

Tags: mysql

Following query will result upper error.

```html
SELECT Farbe,SUM(Anzahl)
FROM bueroklammern
GROUP BY Farbe
HAVING SUM(Anzahl)>

(
 SELECT Farbe,SUM(Anzahl)
 FROM bueroklammern
 WHERE Farbe='gelb'    
);
```

What is wrong with it?
I got it:

```html
SELECT CONCAT('Anzahl aller gelben Büroklammern'), SUM(Anzahl) AS Value
FROM bueroklammern
WHERE Farbe='gelb';

SELECT Farbe,SUM(Anzahl) AS anzahl_is_bigger_as_yellow
FROM bueroklammern
GROUP BY Farbe
HAVING SUM(Anzahl)>
(
SELECT SUM(Anzahl) AS anzahl_gelb
FROM bueroklammern
WHERE Farbe='gelb'
);

SELECT Farbe,SUM(Anzahl) AS anzahl_is_smaller_as_yellow
FROM bueroklammern
GROUP BY Farbe
HAVING SUM(Anzahl)<
(
SELECT SUM(Anzahl) AS anzahl_gelb
FROM bueroklammern
WHERE Farbe='gelb'
);
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Remove the column Farbe from the subquery.`SELECT Farbe,SUM(Anzahl)
 FROM bueroklammern
 WHERE Farbe='gelb' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In having clause SQL query you were evaluating sum of a column with 2 columns in select statement. Use this:

```
 SELECT Farbe, SUM (Anzahl)
    FROM bueroklammern
GROUP BY Farbe  HAVING SUM (Anzahl) > (SELECT  SUM (Anzahl)
                           FROM bueroklammern
                          WHERE Farbe = 'gelb');
```